# undefined method 'entries' for Mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm follow this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes) for setting tags in my application with Mongoid but when I try to save my model I get a NoMethodError like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'entries' for #<Campaign:0x42b10c0>
```

Any hint to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when you try to assign a collection in mongoid to a single model.

For example:

```
user = User.new
user.campaigns = Campaign.new
```

The solution to this particular case is to ensure sure you're wrapping campaign in an Array

```
user.campaigns = [Campaign.new]
```